# using an NUnit category attribute to run certain tests in a dll?

Tags: testing, filter, tdd, nunit, categories

How to programmatically decide which tests to run in NUnit? i.e

```
CoreExtensions.Host.InitializeService();
TestPackage testPackage = new TestPackage(pathToSomeDLL);

// filter by category here??

SimpleTestRunner simpleTestRunner = new SimpleTestRunner();

// or here?
simpleTestRunner.Load(testPackage);

//... maybe here?
testResult = simpleTestRunner.Run(NullListener.NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can supply additional parameters to `SimpleTestRunner`'s `Run` method like so:

```
var filter = new CategoryFilter("MyCategory");
simpleTestRunner.Run(NullListener.NULL, filter, false, LoggingThreshold.Off);
```